# Update specific vector elements in PyTorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, autograd

I have a large vector that I would like to update. I'll update it by adding an offset to specific elements in the vector. I specify a vector of indices that I want to update (call the index vector `ix`), and for each index, I specify a value that I want to add to that element (call the value vector `vals`). If all entries of the index vector are unique, then the following code suffices:

```
vec = torch.zeros(4, dtype=torch.float)
ix = torch.tensor([0,2], dtype=torch.long)
vals = torch.tensor([0.2, 0.5], dtype=torch.float)
vec[ix] += vals
```

However, this does not work if there are repeated indices in `ix`. A naive approach for the case of repeated indices is as follows:

```
for i in range(len(ix)):
    vec[ix[i]] += vals[i]
```

But this doesn't scale well - it is very slow when `ix` is large. Are there any faster ways to do this? If there were a fast way to sum all entries of `vals` that have the same index in `ix`, then the solution should be easy.

**Update:**
I found one solution that works pretty well, described below. I'd still love feedback for better solutions.

```
# get unique indices
ix_unique = torch.unique(ix)

# for each unique index, get sum of all vals with that index
vals_unique = torch.stack([
    torch.sum(torch.where(ix==i, vals, torch.zeros_like(vals))) 
    for i in ix_unique
])

# update vec
vec[ix_unique] += vals_unique
```

Comment: You can write down your own answer, that indicates to others that there is a solution!

Answer (score 0):

For cases where you want to allow multiple updates to the same ix indices, there also exists a library called [pytorch_scatter](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_scatter).
In such cases, having e.g. 3 identical indicies within ix would then result in 3*val being added to that index.

Answer (score 0):

## torch.index_add()

```py
import torch

vec = torch.zeros(4, dtype=torch.float)
ix = torch.tensor([0,0,2], dtype=torch.long)
vals = torch.tensor([0.2,0.1,0.5], dtype=torch.float)
torch.index_add(vec, 0, ix, vals)
```

and you will get

```py
tensor([0.3000, 0.0000, 0.5000, 0.0000])
```

Reference: [official doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=index_add#torch.Tensor.index_add_)